# Type Library correct datatypes for process Handle and PID

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-6

If I needed to translate to types in the Delphi framework, I would use:

- For DWORD: the Cardinal type, used to identify the PID of a process. (tagPROCESSENTRY32)

> ```
> WinAPI DataType | Delphi Translated DataType | Automation Object Compatible DataType
>
> DWORD           | Cardinal                   | ?????
> ```

- For HANDLE, the HWND type, used to map the Handle returned from AllocatedHWND. This will be used latter for Inter Process Communication (IPC)

> ```
> WinAPI DataType | Delphi Translated DataType | Automation Object Compatible DataType
>
> HANDLE(HWND)    | HWND                       | ?????
> ```

However, I need to translate these types to pass them via a COM (type library) interface.

Which are the correct types should I use?

Note: The types needs to be 100% compatible with automation objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose one from [Automation-compatible types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Valid_Types).

`SYSUINT` (ie. `VT_UINT`, `unsigned int`) seem to be your best bet for both if the target platform includes both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. For 32-bit-only, you can choose `LongWord` (`VT_UI4`).

If you don't need an automation-compatible COM library you can also choose `Pointer` for `THandle`.

Comment: I need only an an automation-compatible

Comment: Then you can't use Pointer since it's not an automation-compatible type.

Comment: May you please, address the HWND type part of the question?

Comment: After your edits this answer seems to suit your needs. (You can use `Longword` for both `PID` and `HWND`.)